# Query for multiple mime types (OR-ing)

Tags: google-drive-api

Following the doc https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters on search parameters, I can combine parameters with `and`. `mimeType`-s can be tested with `=`. Can I extract multiple mime types files in one query? No `or` operator in the doc or if I can use `contains` for `mimeType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `or` operator for now. However, you can use [batch](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/83ead9be84f7e697f8140a77d85eb0ce2eee3538/docs/batch.md) call for Drive API to achieve same goal. This will merge multiple queries into one.

---

UPDATE: Please refer to Luke's comment below.

Comment: Is there doc how to batch with C++? What protocol is?

Comment: There's no official support for C++ and I don't know exact protocol for batch request. The easiest way to figure this out is to experiment with Python library, I guess.

Comment: @demi, you can use Cloud storage's reference to implement the batch requests. The formatting is the same for Drive API. https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch

Comment: @BurcuDogan OK, after this question could be closed.

Comment: While I was exploring in Try It section on Google Drive API page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list I found `or` works and parenthesis too.

Comment: Link is outdated, here is a [new one](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/83ead9be84f7e697f8140a77d85eb0ce2eee3538/docs/batch.md)

Answer (score 10):

I feel it's worth noting that demi's last comment is correct I was able to specify a subset of mimtypes as follows:

```
(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or 
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.file' or 
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet')
```

Hope that helps anyone else looking at this question in the future as it is not clear in the documentation.

Comment: is there anything analogous to the SQL `in` operator that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the files and folders by adding this **(mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' or mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')** in **q** parameter.

Your URL will be looks like this -
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=(mimeType%20contains%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.document%27%20or%20mimeType%20contains%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27)

Answer (score -1):

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY&q=(mimeType='application/pdf' or mimeType='image/png')` and trashed = false and 'GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID' in parents

Comment: adding an explanation to your answer would help.